# Where is a list of *all* Spark property keys?

Tags: apache-spark

**Where is a list of *all* (valid, built-in) Spark properties?**

The list of [Available Properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties) on the official Spark documentation does *not* include all (valid, built-in) properties for the current stable version of Spark (2.4.4 as of 2020-01-22).  An example is `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`, which defaults to `200`.  Unfortunately, properties like this one do not appear to be accessible via any of `sparkConf.getAll()`, `sparkConf.toDebugString()`, or `sql.("SET -v")`. 
 Rather, built-in defaults appear to be accessible only by explicit name (i.e. `sparkConf.get("foo")`).  However, this does not help me since the exact property name must be already known, and I need to survey properties that I *don't* already know about for debugging/optimization/support purposes.

Comment: Spark source code on Github would certainly have it

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-sql

Comment: @cricket_007 I may have to just look at the source code then -- that's a good recommendation.  Regarding the link you posted, that doesn't appear to offer anything different than what `sparkConf.getAll()` and `sparkConf.toDebugString()` do; i.e. it has the same limitations what with not display built-in defaults.

Answer (score 3):

you can use.

> sql("SET -v").show(500,false)

Which will give you a near complete list not including the internal properties.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|key                                                              |value                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|spark.sql.adaptive.enabled                                       |false                                            |
|spark.sql.adaptive.shuffle.targetPostShuffleInputSize            |67108864b                                        |
|spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold                             |10485760                                         |
|spark.sql.avro.compression.codec                                 |snappy                                           |
|spark.sql.avro.deflate.level                                     |-1                                               |
...
```

Edit:

I will mention that spark has many baked in defaults that may not show up as config properties.  Id suggest taking a look at the SQLConf class in the source code.  Unfortunately due to the complexity of spark and its nearly untold number of configs not all are in the SQLConf some are scattered throughout the code.  Lately sometimes spark often times has multiple configs that override each other and this can also only be deduced via the source code.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, `sql("SET-v")` does not appear to give any more results than either `sparkConfg.getAll()` or `sparkConf.toDebugString()`.  I.e. built-in defaults that are not explicitly set (e.g. `spark.sql.shuffle.partition 200`) are still not returned.

Comment: @Travis Interesting, considering  that `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` is there https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options Have you tried removing the 500?

Comment: Huh... I am now getting different results than I did last time I ran `sql("SET -v")`. I may have some confounding environment issue. Let me check on that and then get back to you. If nothing else, I'm inclined to go ahead and accept your answer if you could change `...show(500, false)` to `display(...)` in order to display everything in the dataframe.

Comment: It appears that `sql("SET -v")` still does not display all Spark properties. On my instance it displays only properties with the prefix of either `spark.databricks` (proprietary) or `spark.sql`, but not properties such as `spark.executor.memory` which I have verified _is_ set by successfully calling `spark.conf.get("spark.executor.memory")`. (my Databricks instance is {edition: "Databricks Community", runtime: "6.2 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.4, Scala 2.11"}

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you observe additional properties other than those beginning with "spark.sql" when executing `sql("SET -v")`? If so, then do you happen to know whether Databricks' wrapper of Spark implicitly suppress the reporting of certain properties?

Comment: @Travis I've never used databricks, but spark.executor.memory is not a SQL property, therefore it wouldn't show up from that command

Comment: Aha. In that case I cannot accept your answer, since it does not fully answer my question.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing about a method to access the databricks specific config values in addition to the other hidden configs being talked about here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the complete answer, but it can help. It will show more properties than your alternatives. At least will show options modified by some kind of middle ware, like Livy.

Set this parameter:

```
spark.logConf=true
```

Now all your session configuration will be saved in yarn log at level INFO. Do a `yarn logs -applicattionID <your app id>` and search for `spark.app.name=` to find your session properties.

Another problem is that you will see the properties values just after executing the job.